# specifying newlines in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, newline, pom.xml

I need to generate a file with the dependency-jars of project.
This can be done with the dependeny plugin.
See below the snippet from the pom:

```
    <plugin>                   
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.10</version>   
        <execution>            
          <id>list-dependencies</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>              
            <goal>build-classpath</goal>
          </goals>             
          <configuration>
            <prefix></prefix>
            <outputFile>target/modules-list.txt</outputFile>
            <pathSeparator>\n</pathSeparator>                                                                                                                       
          </configuration>  
        </execution>           
      </executions>            
    </plugin>
```

However, since I need each jar on a separate line, I tried to specify the `pathSeparator` to be a newline character. However, this does not work. I didn't find a useful way to specify a newline character in the pom.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Maybe a CDATA section containing a linefeed would work

Comment: @Aaron No, it doesn't. It's like entering a newline directly in the pom. It seems that such whitespace characters are all trimmed away. The only way I found for entering newlines is by surrounding them with printable characters, which really isn't useful.

Comment: Why do you need this? pathSeparator is normally the separator that the OS uses to separate path.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, and the build-classpath goal builds a classpath using this pathSeparator. However, I do not need a classpath, but a list of the jars one per line.

Comment: If you do not need a classpath... don't you think using a goal named `build-classpath` is awkward? It looks like you're using the wrong tool for the job, but which job are you trying to do? (Related: [MDEP-541](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-541))

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, it is akward, but it is the approach that comes closest to what I need: A list of the jar files of all dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML you can specific a newline character using the following escape sequence - `&#x0A;`

Unfortunately, as you already mentioned, the `<pathSeparator>` value is trimmed of all leading and trailing whitespace, effectively resulting in an empty string value causing the plugin to use its default value.

However, you can use an Ant task in the same phase to replace the path separator. For example.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>list-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-classpath</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <prefix></prefix>
                        <outputFile>target/modules-list.txt</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Replace path separator -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <replace file ="target/modules-list.txt" token="${path.separator}" value="${line.separator}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Note that the `<pathSeparator>` is no longer defined in your dependency configuration.

Comment: It isn't unfortunate, it's by design. This goal is intended to build something usable as a classpath, not a general fancy list.

Comment: @Tunaki I gather that the solution is acceptable to you, but the choice of adverbs is not? What would you prefer I change it to - *alas*, *unhappily*, *regrettably*, or *sadly*?   Since the question was a  *How can I do this?* rather than a *Why can't I do this?*, I glossed over explaining the cause to focus on an answer.  radlan's result is not due to the goal's purpose. An element's content under `<configuration>` is trimmed by default, unless a `xml:space="preserve"` attribute is included. Thank you for giving me an opportunity to expand.

Comment: @Frelling While your proposal could work, I will go the way ChrisNauroth describes. But still thanks for your help.

Comment: @radlan I appreciate the feedback; though I am curious. My answer - which speaks for itself - gives you exactly what you asked for, yet you are content with having dangling underscores. Considering that the purpose is for documentation, which implies it will be read by more than just you, how often do you expect someone questioning the significance of trailing underscores, except for in the last line?

Comment: @Frelling Oh, it seems that I have misunderstood your approach. I have tested it and it is even better that ChrisNauroths approach. Therefore I am now accepting your answer (and will actually use it).

Comment: Adding &#x0A; is adding the newline. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maven is trimming your `<pathSeparator>` value, which results in an empty value because the line separator is considered whitespace.  Then, since there is no value, Maven falls back to using the default.  I don't see any easy way to work around this behavior.

There are a few other options.  You could consider using the [`dependency:list`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html) goal:

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>                   
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>list-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>              
        <goal>list</goal>
      </goals>             
      <configuration>
        <outputFile>target/modules-list.txt</outputFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**target/modules-list.txt**

```
The following files have been resolved:
   org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10:compile
   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
   junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
   log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile
   javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
   com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19:compile
   com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19:compile
```

This is the Maven artifact IDs instead of the jar file names.  Arguably, this is actually more valuable, because the output won't change across different machines running the build.  (The jar files would use absolute paths, which might be different across different machines.)

If it really has to be jar file names instead of Maven artifact IDs, then you could cobble something together by injecting a non-whitespace character into the `<pathSeparator>` value, so that even after Maven trims the value, there is something remaining to override the default path separator.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>list-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>build-classpath</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputFile>target/modules-list.txt</outputFile>
        <pathSeparator>_${line.separator}</pathSeparator>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**target/modules-list.txt**

```
/Users/naurc001/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.19/jersey-core-1.19.jar_
/Users/naurc001/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar_
/Users/naurc001/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.19/jersey-server-1.19.jar_
/Users/naurc001/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar_
/Users/naurc001/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar_
/Users/naurc001/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar_
/Users/naurc001/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar_
/Users/naurc001/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

Unfortunately, that leaves you with the ugly underscores at the end.  If you want to clean those up, then you'd need another build step to clean those up.  One approach would be to generate this file in the `generate-resources` phase, and then use [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to do a token substitution during the `process-resources` phase.

Finally, if you just need this information for documentation purposes, consider using the site documentation provided by the [maven-project-info-reports-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html).

Comment: It isn't unfortunate, it's by design. This goal is intended to build something usable as a classpath, not a general fancy list.

Comment: @Tunaki, thank you.  I edited it to remove the word you didn't like.

Comment: @ChrisNauroth Well, it is for documentation purposes, but still I need the jar names. I think that your approach of adding a single underscore is the solution that fits best. Therefore I am accepting your answer.